# What is this node in packet tracer?

Tags: packet-tracer

I figured this would be the best place to try and get an answer. So I'm following a packet tracer tutorial and it contains a node I've never seen before, nor can I find it, it seems to emulate (at least a part of) the internet.

I've tried recreating it using a cloud node and frame-relay, but then I realised the two routers connecting through it aren't on the same network.

[image: Unknown node (internet emulation node?)]

Does anyone know where I can find this node? It doesn't seem to be in packet tracer itself, maybe it's an add-on of some kind? Or is there something I have to configure in the cloud node (which it appears to closely resemble) for it to appear like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a node, that's a cloud representing the Internet. You have no way of knowing how the Internet is connected, so it is represented as a cloud. It represents a whole lot of nodes.

Comment: So will configuring the cloud change to the image above with the two router inside? Or is that just a diagram not created in PT?

Comment: The two routers inside don't represent anything in particular, other than there are routers in the Internet. Basically, it's artwork.

Comment: You could model that node as a (huge) router as that's basically what the Internet does. Your public networks = routes are advertised to that router (in reality: your peers) using BGP. By approximation you can alternatively use static routes in PT.